# Add extra parameter to serializer.data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I get three fields from rest api i.e name , phone number and email id in serializer but i want to store the datetime as well when i receive the api . in database i have created 4 columns i.e name , phone number, email id , created data .
How can i add current date timeparameter to my serializer.data before saving it to posgtresql database table "table_userdetails". please help me with the answers because i am new to it

**Below is the code for views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def UserInfo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = UserDetails.objects.all()
        serializer=UserDetailsSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method =='POST':
        context=datetime.datetime.now()
        serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
        print("serializer",serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Below is the code for Models.py

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
   mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=255)
   email_id=models.CharField(max_length=255)
   user_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   created_date=models.CharField(max_length=255)

   class Meta:
      db_table=table_userdetails 
    
   def __str__(self):
       return self.response
```

Below is my code for serializer.py

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=UserDetails
        fields='__all__'
```

I have added the context part in post method but how to add in serializer.data .please help me with the solution and what am i doing wrong here .any kind of help is appreciated .
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def UserInfo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = UserDetails.objects.all()
        serializer=UserDetailsSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method =='POST':
        serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
        print("serializer",serializer)

        data = serializer.data #fetch the serializer data
        #add current time as key-value pair in data as serializer.data returns a dictionary
        data['current_time'] = datetime.datetime.now()

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            #return the data object/dictionary
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: while attempting this i am gettint this error                                                                    
  "When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead."

Comment: ohh okay wait I'll edit it. Both the lines need to be added after `serializer.is_valid()`.

Comment: Still i am getting some error "You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead."@Ajay Lingayat

Comment: Call it after `serializer.save()`. It will work this time.

Comment: sorry for asking so many questions but calling after the line serializer.save() will not store datetime value in my database . i can see the json response having datetime fileld but in database it is showing null value in column . did i do any step wrong all other fields are getting stored in table except current datetime.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set now to time directly as you could use [`auto_add_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) on `DateTimeField`/`DateField` model field

There is  no sense to keep date in CharField

---

For further reference you could `update()` your `request.data` dictionary with additional attribute as just setting new variable called context does nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can pass extra parameters to the serializers save method.
`serializer.save(created_at=datetime.datetime.now())`

Doing so you will have to take care of validating the data manually, as the serializer will directly save this to the database.

As per your requirement, for `created_at` field, you can use the `auto_now_add=True` attribute in your model field, this will automatically assign the current time to the created_at field. only during the time of creation. Similary for a `updated_at` field you can use `auto_now=True`.

Now if you want to pass extra context to the serializer, you can do so by overriding the `__init__` method.

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time = kwargs.pop('time')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.time = time

    class Meta:
        model=UserDetails
        fields='__all__'
```

Then while initializing the serializer you can pass the value
`serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(data=request.data, time=datetime.datetime.now())`

After that you can use this in the serializer methods. For your requirement, setting the `auto_now_add` attribute will be the best solution.

Edit: If you are using USE_TZ=True in your settings.py you should be using timezone.now()

```
from django.utils import timezone.now()

serializer.save(created_at=timezone.now())
```

Django uses UTC time saved to the database for a timezone aware object, which is converted to the localtime of the user as per the settings.
Refer to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) for more information

Comment: Thank you for the solution!!! auto_now_add worked for me perfectly only issue is i changed timezone in settings.py from 'UTC' to Asia/kolkata  .I am getting a warning message ----" RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField UserDetails.update_date received a naive datetime (2021-01-05 18:46:01.538564) while time zone support is active."

Comment: If you are using USE_TZ=True in your settings.py file then you will need to use timezone.now() to get a timezone aware object. Please see the edit above for clarification.